# ArrayList is being overwritten

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to add a new train to my arraylist but upon adding the train, the existing content of the arraylist gets overwritten by the new input. This results in having only one item in the arraylist without being able to add more without overwriting the other. As I do not quite know what the source of this problem in the code is, I came looking for help here.

Within this class the train is being made:

```
public class RCommand extends RBaseListener {
        Company mycompany = new Company("traincompany");

        @Override 
        public void enterNewtraincommand(RParser.NewtraincommandContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Now creating new train " + ctx.getText());
            mycompany.addTrainTo(new Train(ctx.getChild(2).toString()));
            System.out.println(mycompany.getTrains().size());
        }
}
```

In this class the train is supposed to be added to the list.

```
public class Company{

        private String name;
        List<Train>trains = new ArrayList<Train>();

        public void addTrainTo(Train train) {
                trains.add(train);
                for (Train t :trains) {
                        System.out.println(t.getName());
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize the list of trains in Company's constructor.

Comment: I tried that, but I didn't seem to work. I might have done it wrong though. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Are you sure that RCommand  is not recreated every time you call enterNewtraincommand?

Comment: `trein` Is that a typo?

Comment: @hashmap initializing a member inline is like implicitly initializing it in all the consturtors.

Comment: It's unclear what is the cause of this error. Try debugging or post more code here.

Comment: I don't see an error. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Show your `Train` class.

Comment: This code does not produce the error you described. The problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply test for your class Company to see if if work

```
    public class Test {
        Company company = new Company();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.start();
        }

    private void start() {

    System.out.println("IT work");
    company.addTrainTo(new Train("One"));
    System.out.println("End first add");
    company.addTrainTo(new Train("two"));
    System.out.println("End second add\n");

    System.out.println("Follow example will not work");
    company = new Company();
    company.addTrainTo(new Train("One"));
    System.out.println("End first add");
    company = new Company(); // <--- create the ERROR
    company.addTrainTo(new Train("two"));
    System.out.println("End second add");
    }
}
```

Suppose we have train as is:

```
public class Train {
    private String name;

    public Train(String name) {
        this.name = "Train" + name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Output is:

IT work

Train One

End first add

Train One

Train two

End second add (it work fine)

Follow example will not work

Train One

End first add

Train two

End second add<- we miss the first train because we recreate the company instance

So it work.

So the error is not in this class Company.

1. Check if the caller of Company recreate the class Company before adding new train
2. Check class train if it has something strange (static attribute for name or similar)

Comment: Please explain why down vote? The test demonstrate that class company work fine...

Comment: I do not know who downvoted, but thanks to your code above, I was able track the problem within the code.
You see, everytime I gave the command of adding a new train, the code in the class RCommand was being runned. This resulted in the creation of multiple companies. So I went back to the class that RCommand extends and the class that that class extends (confusing IK) and pasted 'Company mycompany = new Company("traincompany");' there. And now it seems to work.
I was able to find this thanks to you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback :) happy to help someone!

Comment: Chris If this response is fine please give me a point clicking on the up arrow :)!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like new "trains" object is being created for each addition. After adding, try to print the address of "trains" object to find out for sure. You can print the address by System.out.println("trains address is: " + trains)

Answer (score -1):

You did't pass for us all your code required but I think, you should create a Company constructor with your train List.

Something like that:

```
public class Company{

        private String name;
        List<Train>trains;

        public Company(String name, List<Train> trains){
            this.name = name;
            this.trains = trains;
        }

        ...
}
```

Then in your RCommand class use your new Constructor

```
    Company mycompany = new Company(new ArrayList<Train> ,"traincompany");
```

And it will be fine. Your mistake in code is creating new trains list every time by calling `new` operator.